# Delphi code for global notification when a new top level window is created?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, delphi-11-alexandria

I need to be notified whenever a new top-level window is created globally.

This is what I've tried so far (both DLL and host app are 32-bit):

```
library HookDLL;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  CodeSiteLogging;

var
  hHook: Winapi.Windows.HHOOK;

function ShellProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  WindowTitle: array[0..255] of Char;
begin
  if nCode = HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED then
  begin
    GetWindowText(wParam, WindowTitle, 256);
    CodeSite.Send('New window created', Format('HWND: %d, Title: %s', [wParam, WindowTitle]));
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure InstallHook; stdcall;
begin
  if hHook = 0 then
  begin
    hHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, @ShellProc, HInstance, 0);
    if hHook <> 0 then
      CodeSite.Send('Hook set successfully')
    else
      CodeSite.Send('Failed to set hook');
  end;
end;

procedure UninstallHook; stdcall;
begin
  if hHook <> 0 then
  begin
    if UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook) then
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('Hook removed');
      hHook := 0;
    end
    else
      CodeSite.Send('Failed to remove hook');
  end;
end;

exports
  InstallHook,
  UninstallHook;

begin
  hHook := 0;  // Initialize here
end.
```

This is the hosting app:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, CodeSiteLogging;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHook: HHOOK;
    DLLHandle: THandle;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  InstallHookProc: procedure; stdcall;
begin
  CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: 1');

  // Load the DLL once and store the handle in a field for later use
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('HookDLL.dll');  

  if DLLHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: 2');

    @InstallHookProc := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'InstallHook');
    if Assigned(InstallHookProc) then
    begin
      try
        CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: ');
        InstallHookProc;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          CodeSite.Send('Exception in InstallHookProc', E.Message);
        end;
      end;

      // Check for errors
      if GetLastError <> 0 then
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('GetLastError after SetHook', SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: Failed to get InstallHook procedure address');
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: Failed to load DLL');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  UninstallHookProc: procedure; stdcall;
begin
  if DLLHandle <> 0 then  // Assume DLLHandle is a private field of TForm1
  begin
    @UninstallHookProc := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'UninstallHook');
    if Assigned(UninstallHookProc) then
    begin
      try
        UninstallHookProc;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          CodeSite.Send('Exception in UninstallHookProc', E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('Failed to get UninstallHook procedure address');
    end;

    // Check for errors
    if GetLastError <> 0 then
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('GetLastError after Unhook', SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    end;

    // Free the library
    try
      FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('Exception in FreeLibrary', E.Message);
      end;
    end;

    // Check for errors
    if GetLastError <> 0 then
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('GetLastError after FreeLibrary', SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('DLL was not loaded');
  end;
end;

end.
```

It works, as these CodeSite messages are sent:

> TForm1.FormCreate: 1
> TForm1.FormCreate: 2
> TForm1.FormCreate:
> Hook set successfully
> New window created = HWND: 2498578, Title: Form1

Similar messages are sent when I start any Win32 program that opens a window.

However, when I close the above app, any Win32 apps running in the background crash!

Comment: A `WH_SHELL` hook seems like an odd choice. A [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure) hook would appear to be a better option.

Comment: If closing of your application causes other apps to crash I'm guessing that your application is not properly releasing the acquired HOOK. This would then lead to system trying to notify your nonexistent application about hook events. And since you application does not exist at the time the said hook events never get processed and thus resulting hanging apps.

Comment: "_any Win32 apps_" - do you mean **every app** or **a number of apps**? Are messages like "_Hook removed_" sent?

Comment: @SilverWarior But the FormDestroy procedure does call the `UninstallHookProc`, so the Hook is released?

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, the 'Hook removed' message is sent when closing the host app.

Comment: @SilverWarior It seems you were right: For testing, I now do the unhooking from a button click. No more crashes! But how can I reliably do the unhooking when the host app closes?

Comment: Rejoiced too soon - when I close the host app (after having clicked the Unhook button 5 minutes before), it still shuts down the previously opened 32-bit program! (Although the code in the FormDestroy procedure is no longer executed - since commented out).

Comment: I retested it: When I do the UNHOOK in a button click, the same problem arises: also, the IDE gets shut down!

Comment: @IInspectable Do you have an example using `WinEvents`?